# Auto-populate two input boxes from a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to fetch two variables from a mysql db table which is supposed to auto-populate once a user selects a dropdown option.

The dropdown menu will show a list of teams and the input boxes will display the names of the Captain and the Vice-Captain once the team is selected (actually it will only capture their MemberID in the backend and save them in a table)

I had been able to fetch the name of one Captain, using a Javascript function and Ajax. That part is working fine.

What I am after is getting the second captains name/id.

My HTML/PHP code is here:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/capt-dropdown.js"></script> 
...

  <table>
  <?php $x = 0; ?>

    <tr style="background-color:#FFF9C4">
   <td>Select Team: </td>
   <td><select name="teamcode" id="teamcode">
    <option disabled selected value> - Select Team - </option>     
    <?php $sql_select = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT teamcode, team FROM team");
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_select)){
      echo '<option value = " '.$row['teamcode'].'"> '.$row['team'].' </option>';
     } ?>
    </select>
   </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Captain 1: </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="captain1" id="captain1"></td>   
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Captain 2: </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="captain2" id="captain2"></td>     
   </tr>     

    </tr>
  </table>
```

The JS file: capt-dropdown.js

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#teamcode").change(function() {
    var team = $(this).val();
    if(team != "") {
      $.ajax({
        url:"get-captain.php",
        data:{teamcode : team},
        type:'POST',
        success:function(response) {
          var resp = $.trim(response);
          $("#captain1").html(resp);
        }
      });
    } else {
      $("#captain1").html("<option value=''>--- Select ---</option>");
    }
  });
});
```

The php file: get-captain.php is here:

```html
if(isset($_POST['teamcode'])) {
 $teamcode = trim($_POST['teamcode']);
 $sql_select = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT surname, preferred_name, memberid FROM member WHERE memberid in 
 ((SELECT captain FROM captain WHERE year = YEAR(CURDATE())  AND teamcode = '$teamcode'),
 (SELECT vcaptain FROM captain WHERE year = YEAR(CURDATE())  AND teamcode = '$teamcode'))");
 
 while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_select)){
  $name = ($result['surname']. ', '.$result['preferred_name']);
  echo '<option value = " '.$result['memberid']. '">'.$name.'</option>';
 }
}
```

Member table contains the name, surname and member-id of members
Captain table contains historic data of team captains
[Captain table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJPqT.png)

The query in get-captain.php is working, and is able to retrieve the captain and vcaptain’s names & ids.

Read several posts but couldn't find anything similar to what I am doing here.

Can anyone please suggest how to fetch the second captains (the vice-captains) details? (ie. Display his name and capture his member-id)

Pls Note: this is an extract of a form which contains lot of other information, hence my apologies if I missed a line while cutting & pasting here)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I cannot comment yet due to my rep, but captain 1 & 2 are inputs why are you trying to echo out option tags and insert them inside captain1.

You should change get-captain.php to fetch an associative array and `echo json_encode($array);` Your javascript can then parse json array 
`var array=JSON.parse(response);`
 finally putting your array values inside your input

```
$("#captain1").html(arr[0]["surname"] + "," + arr[0]["preferred_name"]);
$("#captain1").val(arr[0]["memberid"]);
$("#captain2").html(arr[1]["surname"] + "," + arr[1]["preferred_name"]);
$("#captain2").val(arr[1]["memberid"]);
```

If your dealing with more than 2 captains then you can just loop through your array and add a counter. Hope this makes sense i've never been good at explaining.